# How to get one photos from one album using flickr api

Tags: flickr

I am integrating  Flickr API in my application.
I want to display Flickr photos one photo per album.

Comment: Have you already tried anything?

Comment: i am trying to find from https://www.flickr.com/services/api  but still not find any solution, do you any solution?